# matplotlib Qt5Agg backend error: 'figure' is an unknown keyword argument

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt5

I am running python 3.5, via an up-to-date anaconda distribution, on windows 7.  When I use Qt5Agg as the matplotlib backend (set via my matplotlibrc file), I get the error in the subject line.  It is very simple to reproduce:

- Start python from a cmd.exe prompt
- from pylab import *
- figure(1)

Same problem in ipython.

Thoughts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.  I found the solution [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5650/)

Specifically, the following now works:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
plt.title("Score")
plt.show()
```