# backend_qt5.py "'figure' is an unknown keyword argument, In matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to run a  simple code to plot my data using matplotlib in python2.7.10 :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y=[23,35,43,54,76]
x=[2,4,5,6,7]
plt.plot(y,x)
```

I am getting the error:

```
super(FigureCanvasQTAggBase, self).__init__(figure=figure)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py", line 239, in __init__
super(FigureCanvasQT, self).__init__(figure=figure)
TypeError: 'figure' is an unknown keyword argument
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: It seems like `qt5` somehow acts as backend for your plot. The error message does not come from within your file. Apart from that, `x` and `y` have different dimensions, you should fix that.

Comment: I find that this usually means I'm not passing the correct args to lib.  The args for ``pyplot.plot()`` aren't the greatest and it might be the mismatched number x/y as @mwormser points out, however it seems technically the docs say ``plot`` takes a variable number of x/y pairs.

Comment: Actually I am just trying some code from  kagglehttps://www.kaggle.com/shudima/digit-recognizer/randomforest-with-scikit-learn
Earlier it was working fine, I have used it. I am not getting you, How to fix it. What I've to do

Comment: Even If I change the dimension I am getting the same problem.

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5650/

Comment: Hi, yes there's problem with the back-end Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be a duplicate of: [matplotlib Qt5Agg backend error: 'figure' is an unknown keyword argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37164875/matplotlib-qt5agg-backend-error-figure-is-an-unknown-keyword-argument/41018720#41018720), which I just posted an answer for, and duplicated below:

> I had the same issue.  I found the solution [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5650/)
>
> Specifically, the following now works:
>
> ```
> import matplotlib
> matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
> from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
>
>
> plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
> plt.title("Score")
> plt.show()
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to Marc's answer. If you are using Spyder,

`matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')`

may not work well because matplotlib has been imported when you open Spyder.

Instead you can go to (in Spyder) Tools - Preferences -IPython console - Graphics to change the backend and restart Spyder.

Answer (score 0):

adding to this, i ran into this problem when i wanted to plot my values for my KNN training sets and test set results.

using TkAgg also fixes the problem
"**matplotlib.use('TkAgg')**"

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
#matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
plt.title("Score")
plt.show()
```